# Convert Magento 1 Script to Magento 2 (Get Order ID by custom Block)

Tags: magento2, module, custom-block

I am trying to get the ORDER ID, BaseSubtotalInclTax, BaseShippingInclTax, and TaxAmount on the success.phtml page by using custom block.

On Magento 1 I had to put the following script in the success.phtml file.

```
    <?php 
    $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    ?>

    order_id: '<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()); ?>',
    revenue:  '<?php echo $order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax(); ?>',  
    shipping: '<?php echo $order->getBaseShippingInclTax(); ?>',
    Total Shipping Cost. <?php $shippingc= $order->getBaseCodTaxAmount(); 
    if ($shippingc!= NULL)
    {
        $finaltax= ($order->getTaxAmount() - $shippingc);
    }
    else
    {
        $finaltax= $order->getTaxAmount();
    }
    ?>
    tax:      '<?php echo $finaltax; ?>'    // Total Tax.
    }));



    <?php
    $orderItems = array();
    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) 
    {

    $row=array();
    $row['sku'] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
    $row['original_price'] = $item->getOriginalPrice();
    $row['price'] = $item->getPrice();
    $row['qty_ordered']= (int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
    $row['subtotal']= $item->getSubtotal();
    $row['tax_amount']= $item->getTaxAmount();
    $row['tax_percent']= $item->getTaxPercent();
    $row['discount_amount']= $item->getDiscountAmount();
    $row['row_total']= $item->getRowTotal();
    $row['name']= $item->getName();




    $orderItems[]=$row;

        if ($row['price'] != 0)
        {   echo    "order_id: '".$orderId."',";
            echo    "product_id: '".$row['sku']."',";
            echo    "name: '".$row['name']."',";
            echo    "price: '".$row['original_price']."',";
            echo    "quantity: '".$row['qty_ordered']."'";
        }

    }

?>
```

I am trying to do that in my custom block on Magento 2. Without success...

**app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/Block/Success.php**

```
<?php
namespace Clud7\Skroutz\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
class Success  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    public function getOrder($id) {
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $orderid=$objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('increment_id',array('eq',$id))->getFirstItem()->getId();
       return $this->orderRepository->get($orderid);
    }


    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'returned something from custom block.';
    }


    public function skroutz()
    {   
        $start= '<br /><br />SKROUTZ FEEDBACK STARTS HERE<br /><br />';
        $end='<br /><br />SKROUTZ FEEDBACK ENDS HERE<br /><br />';
        return $start .'returned something from custom block'.$end;
    }


}
```

**app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml**

```
<?php
 $order = $block->getOrder($block->getOrderId()); 
 $orderid=$block->getOrderId();
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
 $order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);
 $ordercollection=$order->getItemsCollection()->getData();
?>



<?php 
 echo 'START TEST GET ORDER ID <br />';
 echo  "Order ID:".$orderid."<br/>";
 echo 'END TEST GET ORDER ID <br />';
?>
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: you have the function getOrder() in your block and in phtml you are calling getOrderId()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to get order information is by `public function __construnction`

Here is the correct code for **app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/Block/Success.php**

```
<?php
namespace Clud7\Skroutz\Block;

class Success  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $_orderFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_product;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
     */
    protected $_catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $_order;
    /**
     * constructor class
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session                                               $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory                                             $orderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product                                                $product
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable    $catalogProductTypeConfigurable
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context                              $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();

        if ($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId()) {
            $this->_order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
        }
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Returns the id of the last order
     *
     * @return integer|boolean
     */
    public function getRealOrderId()
    {
        $order = $this->_order;
        if ($order) {
            $lastorderId = $order->getId();
            return $lastorderId;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the order subtotal with added tax and shipping fee
     *
     * @return string|boolean
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        $order = $this->_order;
        if ($order) {
            $price = number_format($order->getSubtotalInclTax() + $order->getShippingInclTax(), 2);
            return $price;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the order shipping fee
     *
     * @return string|boolean
     */
    public function getShippingCost()
    {
        $order = $this->_order;
        if ($order) {
            $shippingCost = number_format($order->getShippingInclTax(), 2);
            return $shippingCost;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the order tax amount
     *
     * @return string|boolean
     */
    public function getTaxAmount()
    {
        $order = $this->_order;
        if ($order) {
            $revenuefortax = $order->getSubtotalInclTax() + $order->getShippingInclTax();
            $taxtotal = $revenuefortax / 1.24;
            $taxAmountAlmost = $revenuefortax - $taxtotal;
            $taxAmount = number_format($taxAmountAlmost, 2);
            return $taxAmount;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Returns all order items
     *
     * @return array|boolean
     */


}

?>
```

and **app/code/Clud7/Skroutz/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml**

```
<?php

$block->getRealOrderId();
//$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
//$order = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);
//$ordercollection=$order->getItemsCollection()->getData();

echo 'START TEST GET ORDER ID <br />';

echo  "Order ID:".$block->getRealOrderId()."<br/>";
echo  "Price Incl Tax: ".$block->getPrice()."<br />";
echo  "Tax:" .$block->getTaxAmount()."<br />";
echo 'END TEST GET ORDER ID <br />';


?>
```